# Remove/replace hindi font in C# regex

Tags: c#, regex

" **** दुनिया की सबसे बेस्ट कंपनी *** the zzzz is best company in world "

I have remove/replace Hindi Font in String in `mvc` `c#` with `regex` .

plz Help Me . .

Comment: Possible dupliacate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523814/what-are-the-unicode-ranges-for-hindi-accented-characters

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
\p{IsDevanagari}
```

See it working [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=6346d64c-2c0b-4022-879c-4798c9f871e2) (characters are replaced with `X`).