# How to detect if a string contains hindi (devnagri) in it with character and word count

Tags: regex, powershell, unicode, hindi

Below is a example string -

```
$string = "abcde वायरस abcde"
```

I need to check weather this string contains any Hindi (Devanagari) content and if so the count of characters and words. I guess regex with  unicode character class can work http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html. But I am not able to figure out the correct regex statement.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523814/what-are-the-unicode-ranges-for-hindi-accented-characters

Comment: You can specify a unicode range inside a regular expression and do something as follows:
<code>
test="abcde वायरस abcde";
devanagariCount=test.match(new RegExp('[\u0900-\u097F]+',"g")).length;
nonDevanagariCount=test.match(new RegExp('[^\u0900-\u097F]+',"g")).length;
</code>

For ranges consult the following: http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To find out, if a string contains a Hindi (Devanagari) character, you need to have a full list of all Hindi characters. According to [this website](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0900-097F), the Hindi characters are the hexadecimal characters between `0x0900` and `0x097F` (decimal 2304 to 2431).

The regular expression pattern needs to match, if any of those characters are in the set. Therefore, you can use a pattern (actually a set of characters) to match the string, which looks like this:

`[\u0900\u0901\u0902` ... `\u097D\u097E\u097F]`

Because it is rather cumbersome to manually write this list of characters down, you can generate this string by iterating over the decimal characters from 2304 to 2431 or over the hexadecimal characters.

To count all words containing at least one Hindi character, you can use the following pattern. It contains white-space (`\s`) around the word or the beginning (`^`) or the end (`$`) around the word, and a global flag, to match every occurence (`/g`):

`/(?:^|\s)[\u0900\u0901\u0902` ... `\u097D\u097E\u097F]+?(?:\s|$)/g`

**Here is a live implementation in JavaScript:**

```js
var numberOfHindiCharacters = 128;
var unicodeShift = 0x0900;
var hindiAlphabet = [];
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfHindiCharacters; i++) {
  hindiAlphabet.push("\\u0" + (unicodeShift + i).toString(16));
}

var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)["+hindiAlphabet.join("")+"]+?(?:\\s|$)", "g");
var string1 = "abcde वायरस abcde";
var string2 = "abcde abcde";

[ string1.match(regex), string2.match(regex) ].forEach(function(match) {
  if(match) {
    console.log("String contains " + match.length + " words with Hindi characters only.");
  } else {
    console.log("String does NOT contain any words with Hindi characters only.");
  }
});
```

Comment: Why don't just use the class `[\u0900-\u097F]`

Comment: ```re.search(r'\p{Devanagari}',sname)``` will [also](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) work.

Comment: Sorry but, why is this the accepted answer? What happened to ranges?

Answer (score 6):

It should be a range. The list of all characters is not required.
The following will detect a Devanagari word

```
[\u0900-\u097F]+
```