# Count number of "letters"/characters for non-Western language (e.g. Hindi)

Tags: r, letter

I want to count the number of "letters" in non-Western languages like Hindi. I put the letters in parenthesis, because if I'm not mistaken, e.g. in Mandarin a character does not necessarily represent a letter, but more like a word.

Anyway, so with Western languages, the following works:

```
library(stringr)
western_text <- "This is my text"
str_count(tolower(western_text), "[a-z]")

# [1] 12
```

Now I try the same with a Hindi response:

```
hindi_text <- "बहुत सी"
str_count(tolower(hindi_text), "[a-z]")

# [1] 0
```

So question is how I can count the letter equivalent of the Hindi (and potentially other non-Western like Mandarin, Kyrillic...) alphabet(s)?

Update: I guess I will probably need to create some sort of lookup list of all non-Western alphabets to match against?

Comment: Have a look here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41356013/how-to-detect-if-a-string-contains-hindi-devnagri-in-it-with-character-and-wor>

Comment: Good source. Thanks for finding it!

Answer (score 1):

**Hindi:**

```
hindi_text <- "बहुत सी"
str_count(hindi_text)
[1] 5
```

**Bulgarian**

```
bulgarian_text <- "НаРаВЯне"
str_count(tolower(bulgarian_text))
[1] 8
```

**Amharic**

```
amharic_text <- "ጆሮ"
str_count(amharic_text)
[1] 2
```

**Russian**

```
russian_text <- "солнце"
str_count(russian_text)
[1] 6
```

**Arabic**

```
arabic_text <- "الله"
str_count(arabic_text)
[1] 4
```

Right?

For insurance, you can pass additionally your string through `enc2utf8`.

---

**An addition:**

```
russian_text <- "СОлнЦЕ3333 "
str_count(tolower(russian_text), "[а-я]")
[1] 6
```

**A new addition:**

```
hybrid_text <- "СОлнЦЕ3333 girl "
str_count(tolower(hybrid_text), c("[а-я]", "[a-z]"))
[1] 6 4
```

Comment: Thanks for this hint. That's a good start. However, this will count indeed the characters, not only letters, e.g. "солнце " gives 7 characters. And it also gives some incorrect results when adding numbers, e.g. "солнце0" still gives 6 as result, not 7.

Comment: @deschen look to an addition. We should return [a-z], but for every language separately )

Comment: Ok, so it basically requires to specify the respective alphabet similar to the Western [a-z]. Which makes sense. I just hoped there is some shortcut to reference any/all alphabets in one command. But I see that this is a bit naive to hope.

Comment: @deschen Look to the next addition ;)

Comment: Yes yes, that‘s what I meant, I need to specify the Western, Kyrillic, Japanese….alphabet. With „one command“ I was more refeering to the question of there is a function that gives me the info about letters in any language without having to specify the alphabet/letters.

Comment: @deschen Look to ```nchar``` or ```stri_count``` + regex to exclude digits and punctuation marks.