# capturing phrases in quotes though regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I might be asking repeated question but I am not able to find solution to my problem so please spare!
I need to capture phrases enclosed in quotes through regex. That is easy , but problem arises when there is no uniformity of quotes like in the following case
`'सीक्रेट सुपरस्टार'` and `‘ डॉन 2 ’`
I tried using `re.findall(r"['(.*?)' |‘(.*?)’] ",text)` . But this doesn't work out.
I need one regex to find phrases enclosed in different type of quotes.

Comment: Remove whitespace and `[` and `]`.

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9523932/5513005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?:(')|(‘))(.*?)(?(1)'|(?(2)’))
```

See the [regex demo](https://ideone.com/fkhymW).

**Details**

- `(?:(')|(‘))` - match and capture `'` (put it into Group 1) or match and capture `‘` (and put it into Group 2)
- `(.*?)` - match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?(1)'` - if Group 1 matched, match `'`
- `|` - else
- `(?(2)’` - if Group2 matched, match `’`
- `))` - end of conditional construct.

See the [Python 2.7 demo](https://ideone.com/fkhymW) below:

```
rx = ur'''(?:(')|(‘))(.*?)(?(1)'|(?(2)’))'''
s=u"'सीक्रेट सुपरस्टार' and ‘ डॉन 2 ’"
for x in re.finditer(rx, s):
    print(x.group(3).encode("utf8"))
```

Output:

```
सीक्रेट सुपरस्टार
 डॉन 2
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But i need to add more conditions to check for the phrases like text enclosed in " सुपरस्टार " or some other type of quotes. With above solution I am able to capture only 2 condition . IS there a way to include multiple conditions?

Comment: Yes, just add more capturing groups in the first `(?:...)` group as alternatives, add more checks to the conditional construct at the end. You might also try another way of matching the strings, like `["'‘](.*?)["'’]`. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/GKXCjL). Or even [`['"‘]([^'"‘]*)['"’]`](https://ideone.com/Y6Dazl). Check these regexes [**here**](https://regex101.com/r/5D4SpO/1).